# How to Link To a Border Instead of <p>, <h1>, <h2>, etc

Tags: html

I have a long one-page HTML webpage with anchored links (llorch.org). But I want links to the blue border instead of h2.

```
<h2><a name="AboutMe">Sobre m&#237;</a></h2>.
```

In order to make that possible, I tried to link to div instead of h1. So.

```
<a name="expositio1"><div class="expositio"></a>
<h2><a name="AboutMe">Sobre m&#237;</a></h2>
```

And it works: http://jsfiddle.net/jv4cK/

But it's not validated.

Is there another way to link to a border? Oh, I forgot to say: it works in every browser, except IE. IE makes this weird border above the blue one.

Comment: Any specific reason for doing that?

Comment: Mostly an aesthetics reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you currently have:

```
<div class="expositio"><a name="expositio2"></a>
```

Adjust it to use:

```
<div class="expositio" id="expositio2">
```

The existing bookmark for `#expositio2` should jump to an element with this id. Using the `name` attribute is actually deprecated, so using an id is the correct way to do this.

Comment: As simple as that. And I learned something today. That´s, Steve!